# Counting Differences within a Case-When

Tags: postgresql, case-when

I'm trying to do some analytics on user activity, specifically how many users are still active, or at least logging in, over a period of time.  However I have some conflicting numbers with the first months count which should just be the count of users that signed up during a month.  To figure that out, my simple query is this.

```
SELECT count(user_id)
FROM users
WHERE date_part('year', member_since) = 2013 
AND date_part('month', member_since) = 01
```

Hypothetically this returns '1,000' which I believe to be correct because of the simplicity. But if I do this...

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN date_part('day', last_login - member_since) >= 0 
    THEN user_id END) days_0
FROM users
WHERE date_part('year', member_since) = 2013 
AND date_part('month', member_since) = 01
```

...It will return a number less than 1,000.  Theoretically this should return the same number as above because even if last_login is the same day as member_since that would be zero and should count those users.  Both member_since and last_login are 'timestamp' types.  I have a hunch that the difference could be users where last_login is the exact same as member_since, meaning that they signed up and never came back, but I'm not sure how I would test this.  Is this a NULL issue?  If so, how could I include that to get back to the count of '1,000'?

Comment: try this query `select * from users where last_login is null or member_since is null or date_part('day', last_login - member_since) < 0`

Comment: is it returns something than you have some inconsistent rows

Answer (score 0):

I would bet dollars to donuts that you nulls are what are causing the problem since they will always hit the else statement.

To correct for that, try this:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN last_login is null or date_part('day', last_login - member_since) >= 0 
    THEN user_id END) days_0
FROM users
WHERE date_part('year', member_since) = 2013 
AND date_part('month', member_since) = 01;
```